# Search for string on a file and copy the line if found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have to files to compare and if found copy and missing text/string to **File3.**

**File1**

```
GLOBAL
MERCI
DATA
```

**File2**

```
GLOBAL:11.22.33
MERCI:23.12.43
DATA:76.11.45
AWS:99.32.15
```

How can i achieve this, search text from **File1** to **File2**. If found, create a 3rd file and add the missing info.

**File3** should be like this

```
GLOBAL:11.22.33
MERCI:23.12.43
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SO is not a please-create-a-script-for-me service. Please show what you have tried yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
awk -F":" 'FILENAME=="c"{A[$1]=$1} FILENAME=="d"{if(A[$1]==$1){print}}' c d
```

c and d are the two file names

Comment: oh it work perfectly.. thank you so much @yoga. i initially use for loop but it's not displaying the correct output. thank you so much.. really appreciate your help.. cheers!